# Date Time Comparison Not Working As Expected in PHP even when using a Date Object

Tags: php, date, time

I have the following code but its not working as expected even though I am using a DateTime object as suggested by some posts and not to use strtotime()

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('september 1st, 2016');
$now = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix') );

echo 'Date: '. $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br />';
echo 'Now: '. $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br />';
if($date < $now) {
   echo '<b>Date is less than now</b>';
 }
 else
 {
     echo '<b>Date is greater than now</b>';
 }
```

and the output I get is below, but how is it possible.

```
 Date: 2016-09-01 00:00:00
 Now: 2016-08-31 21:24:11

 Date is less than now
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these lines:

```
$date = new DateTime('september 1st, 2016');   // default timezone
$now = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix') ); // timezone is set
```

They both have different time zone of around 3 and half hours that's why the time is different.

Comment: Good answer! Phoenix time would have an offset of 7 hours to UTC, so the UTC time of `$now` would be "2016-09-01 04:24:11".